# Array of function pointers in C with different return types and arguments

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have 3 functions with different return types and different arguments. I am trying to create an array of function pointers and then call them afterwards. But its not working. Please provide some suggestions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Array of function pointers (different return types and parameters) */

void sayHello()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int twice(int a)
{
    return 2*a;
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    int(*add_ptr)(int,int) = NULL;
    void(*hello_ptr)(void) = NULL;
    int(*twice_ptr)(int) = NULL;

    void * func_table[] = {(void *)sayHello, (void *)add, (void *)twice};


    printf("Add : %d\n", ((add_ptr)func_table[1])(10,5));
    printf("Hello : \n",((hello_ptr)func_table[0])());
    printf("Twice : %d\n",((twice_ptr)func_table[2])(10));
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I have edited the code to look like :

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Array of function pointers (different return types and parameters) */

void sayHello()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int twice(int a)
{
    return 2*a;
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    typedef int(*add_ptr)(int,int);
    typedef void(*hello_ptr)(void);
    typedef int(*twice_ptr)(int);

    void * func_table[] = {(void *)sayHello, (void *)add, (void *)twice};


    printf("Add : %d\n", ((add_ptr)func_table[1])(10,5));
    printf("Hello : ",((hello_ptr)func_table[0])());
    printf("Twice : %d\n",((twice_ptr)func_table[2])(10));
    return 0;
}
```

But still I am getting the error :

```
error: invalid use of void expression
  printf("Hello : ",((hello_ptr)func_table[0])());
  ^
```

Comment: "_But its not working_" - Please explain *what* isn't working.

Comment: You can only cast to _types_ not _variables_. `int a;
    printf("%d\n", (int)3.14);` would compile and will output `3` but `int a;
    printf("%d\n", (a)3.14);` will not.

Comment: http://ideone.com/GXveEC

Comment: A function pointer does not necessarily fit in a `void *`.  So for portability reasons, code has undefined behavior - UB.  Recommend using a `union` rather than `void *`.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it is (now) perfectly clear what the problem is, and the user should be given a _correct_ answer.

Comment: Could you explain what you intended to happen when you tried to get the return value of a void function call?

Comment: @DanGetz : I don't want to get the return value of a void function call. I just put it with `printf`. Is it a wrong usage, really?

Comment: You put its return value as an argument to `printf`, because it's inside the `()` of `printf`. That's what it means in every other place where you put a function call inside the `()`.

Comment: @DanGetz : Actually, I expected it to be ignored,as the return type was void...

Comment: @InsaneCoder so `add(sayHello(), twice(2), sayHello(), sayHello(), twice(3), sayHello())` would be the same as `add(twice(2), twice(3))`? Not in any language I'm familiar with. This is the error your compiler is showing you.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want `add_ptr`, `hello_ptr`, and `twice_ptr`  to be function pointer *types* (since you're casting to them) rather than variables:

```
typedef int(*add_ptr)(int,int);
typedef void(*hello_ptr)(void);
typedef int(*twice_ptr)(int);
```

Alternatively, if you meant for `add_ptr`, `hello_ptr`, and `twice_ptr` to be variables and assign the elements of `func_table` to those variables, then:

```
add_ptr = func_table[1];
hello_ptr = func_table[0];
twice_ptr = func_table[2];
printf("Add : %d\n", add_ptr(10,5));
printf("Hello : "); hello_ptr();
printf("Twice : %d\n", twice_ptr(10));
```

---

Also, you don't need to cast to `void*` here:

```
void * func_table[] = {sayHello, add, twice};
```

---

Also, your zero-parameter functions `sayHello` and `main` are missing the keyword `void` in their parameter list. They should look like this:

```
void sayHello(void) { … }
int main(void) { … }
```

Comment: Yes. Do I need to `typedef`? Why? I am confused ....

Comment: `typedef void(*hello_ptr)(void);` should be `typedef void(*hello_ptr)();`, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy It should be with `void`. The declarations of `sayHello` and `main` are missing `void` in their argument list.

Comment: @InsaneCoder Because you want to declare `add_ptr` (et al.) as a type, not as a variable. Or maybe you just want to assign `func_table[1]` to the `add_ptr` variable. The syntax for that is `add_ptr = func_table[1];`.

Comment: @tuple_cat Yes. That'll do as well. I suggest mentioning it in your answer.